# How to find arbitrary functions resulting from partial integration when finding vector potential for a magnetostatic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, symmetry, differential-equations

I have solved a partial differential equation (with the aid of Mathematica) to yield this result:

$$
A_{\phi}(\rho , z) =\gamma \Bigg(  \frac{z^2 -\rho z + \rho^2}{3 \rho (\rho^2 + z^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}} + \frac{c(\rho + z)}{\rho}\Bigg)
$$

Where $A_{\phi}(\rho, z)$ represents a component of a magnetic vector potential in cylindrical coordinates, with contributions from the $B_{\rho}$ and $B_{z}$ only. The magnetic field is rotationally invariant so I have ingnored the derivatives with respect to $\phi$ in these components. As my system is infinite my only boundary condition is $A_{\phi}(\infty, z) = 0$ but clearly by putting this into my expression both terms will be zero, not helping at all to find the arbitary function, $c(\rho +z)$.

Are there any other conditions or relations I am missing to find this function? Or is this function a degree of freedom resulting on the gauge I chose as its value should have no contribution to my magnetic field?

For context the equation I am solving is:

$$
\frac{\partial (\rho A_{\phi})}{\partial \rho} - \frac{\partial A_{\phi}}{\partial z} =  \gamma \Bigg( \frac{\rho z +z^2}{(\rho^2 +z^2)^{5/2}} \Bigg)
$$

Thank you!

Comment: I might be missing something. Why does $c(\rho +z)/\rho$ go to zero when $\rho \rightarrow \infty$?

Comment: I recon (like @RobJeffries), that your vector potential goes to constant as $\rho\to\infty$ for any fixed $z$. This implies magnetic field $\mathbf{B}\propto \mathbf{\hat{z}}/\rho$, which does go to zero at infinity. Is this sufficient?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates.

Basically, are you sure the vector potential has to vanish at infinity, or is it sufficient for magnetic field to do so?